# Make an Imageview assume the biggest width allowed by its parent

Tags: android, android-layout

I want an Imageview to expand and assume the biggest width respecting the parent viewgroups margins. The width of the parent must however behave like `wrap_content` when the ImageView is dynamically hidden.
Consider the following layout:

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingLeft="8dp"
    android:paddingRight="8dp">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:src="@drawable/strasse_hintergrund"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Short Text"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

The following images show what the layout looks like, both with a short and a long text in the textview:

[image: Layout with short text]
[image: Layout with long text]

I need the ImageView to always have assume width as in the second version (with the long text).

What is the best way to achieve this?

Comment: It sounds like you're asking for impossible behavior. You want a parent's width to be defined by its child, but you want the child's width to be limited by the parent too.

Comment: No, I do not want the parent to entirely determine the width - The parent effectively constrains the maximum width of the child with WRAP_CONTENT in the default case too, which is all control I want from the parent.

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:src="@drawable/strasse_hintergrund"/>
```

and maybe change :

```
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
```

to

```
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
```

EDIT :

Here is my code :

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:weightSum="1">




    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="19dp"
        android:background="@color/dark"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
        android:layout_weight="0.02">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"

            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="7pt"
            android:textColor="@color/white"/>

    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="10pt"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Result :

[image]

Comment: It seems it works in the layout preview now. But when I dynamically load an image into the imageview at runtime, the size is still tiny

Comment: Have you tested it on an android emulator ?

Once I get back home, i'll compare with one of my project. I do have one project with fitXY and it work perfectly

Comment: I have tested it on a Moto G2 with running android 6.0.

Comment: See my code below, it may help you since for me it work perfectly.

Comment: So I suppose, the analogy woudl be with id/imageView and id/textView. The way I understand it is, that it works because you have android:layout_width="match_parent" in your LinearLayout. But then, if you hide the ImageView in code, the layout won't shrink to Wrap around the TextView anymore - so it does not do what I want.

Comment: Which is waht i meant by "The width of the parent must however behave like wrap_content when the ImageView is dynamically hidden."

Answer (score 0):

1. Place `TextView` and `ImageView` in different `LinearLayout`s and place both inside a third `LinearLayout` OR
2. use `match_parent` instead of `wrap_content` for your `TextView` width

Answer (score 0):

You can set this `android:scaleType="fitXY"` property for Imageview

```
<ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/your_image"/>
```